# How can I treat an insecure origin as secure using localhost with a subdomain?

Tags: google-chrome, getusermedia

I am working on an application that uses multitenancy and also has subdomains. The main domain `http://localhost:3000` does not have the features on it that I am trying to test, so I am testing on `http://subdomain.localhost:3000`. I am using a webcam protocol that uses `getUserMedia()` which Chrome disallows on non-secure origins. Normally this would be fine on `localhost`, but because of the subdomain, Chrome disallows this. How can I get around this?